# TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'NoneType' objects error when working with bottle.py

Tags: python, html, bottle

[image: function]

sendconfirm() basically takes the variables and uses them to send an email, but when it goes to send it gets confused with the date variable

[image: form for the date]

[image]

I have tried looking around on the good old google, and I can't find anything that works relating to my specific issue, other posts say to use str(obj) or repr(obj) but they don't work, also I basically what it is, apparently it is because it has a 'none' attribute to it, so that's why it can't do it, but I still don't understand how to fix my issue

so any help would be appreciated

Comment: Please post the actual code instead of screenshots and please also post the full traceback. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

You can print the values as a form of debugging, but I don't think it's the date. Double check the value of request.forms.get('palce') against the name of the form field. That seems to be a typo which would generate a None value.

Comment: thanks for spotting the typo, however i am still getting the same error, and it is saying it is because the date, it says 'in line 55' then is shows ` "Date - " + date + "\n ...`

Comment: also when i do `print(type(date))` it says that it is a string, so idk why it is happening

Answer (score -1):

i went back to the previous page after reloading the script, however, i never actually reloaded the chrome window